# XML inspection tool

Tags: windows, data-visualization, xml, text-search, validation

I develop a lot with XML and use mostly [XmlSpy](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAA&url=http://www.altova.com/de/xmlspy.html&ei=lwv5UtbLNYqF0QGA1YDYBA&usg=AFQjCNGE6gGwh6zohBt6MP58oaLAXpQ42Q&bvm=bv.60983673,d.dmQ). It's really great and also really expensive. I am looking for a cheaper/free alternative.

Must-haves:

- XML grid view (viewing the XML structure like a datagrid/tree)
- generate XML data from XSD files and vise-versa
- check XML files for validity and being well-formed
- load very big XML files really fast
- Of course all common features like text search in files and so on

Nice-to-haves:

- generate (C#) source code from XSD files

Are there such tools?

Answer (score 8):

[XPontus](http://xpontus.sourceforge.net/features.html): Doesn't *quite* meet 100% but probably as close as you'll get without shelling out currently; and OS so could be extended at some point to fully match. Certainly does match that cheaper - since it is *free*.

1. *XML grid view:* hmm not 100% sure what you mean by that but I there is a tree view which I think is what you're meaning (I have limited experience with XML though I'm learning a lot - Revenue Canada has great resources actually)
2. *generate XML data from XSD files and vise-versa:* Can generate schemas (of a few different kinds: DTDS, XML schemas, and Relax NG grammars) from XML documents. See screenie below for the *New from Template* option options.
3. *check XML files for validity and being well-formed:* Has a validity checker.
4. *load very big XML files really fast:* I don't have any that I'd call big so can't comment on this (pretty much instant for 1500 line xml files on my HP Intel i7 2gb Ram Laptop)
5. *Of course all common features...:* mostly - **specifically missing:** Search in *files*.

*No Bonus Points:* Doesn't generate C (or any other) source code.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: To my mind anyways not matching 100% is not a good reason to downvote the answer - if it is close and specifies areas that don't match the requirements I'd upvote an answer on my question even if it isn't the answer I choose to accept

Comment: The reason for downvote is especially not given when the answer is *close* ***and*** the miss is even pointed out.

Comment: [Meta related](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/563/how-should-we-threat-answers-that-doesnt-fit-all-requirements)

Comment: If you need a big XML file, download the Stack Overflow data dump.

Comment: For an explanation of grid view, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51396/gratis-xml-editor-with-grid-view  This app does not seem to have it :-(

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse XML tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-xml-editors-and-tools-0) do most of this. (See screenshot tab on their homepage)

- *XML grid view (viewing the XML structure like a datagrid/tree)*

  - there is a "Design View" and a "Source View". The Design View is not a nested grid, but a pretty tree.
- *generate XML data from XSD files and vice-versa*

  - XSD to XML: there is a Wizard for that. select New File... XML File ... From XML Schema File.
  - XML to XSD: not possible (?) but do you really need it that often?
- check XML files for validity and being well-formed

  - the Validate checker is under the "Context Menu" (right mouse click)
- load very big XML files really fast

  - limited by your JVM options and your RAM
- Of course all common features like text search in files and so on

  - the GUI and general features of Eclipse IDE are pretty sophisticated, a lot of refinements went into this