# Gratis XML editor with grid view

Tags: windows, gratis, data-visualization, xml, editor

At work, we use [XML Spy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor). It is very impressive, but it also costs Eur 399 for a single license.

I am looking for an alternative; it must be gratis, for Windows (or cross platform), with full text view, tree view, and, most importantly, grid view, like this:

[image]

Beyond that, just standard features, like find/replace, etc The more the merrier, but gratis/cheap & grid view are the important ones.

---

[Update] I want round trip editting. The grid should not just be for looking at. I want to be able to edit the grid and have it upate the underlying XML.

Comment: Related : https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/884/xml-inspection-tool

Comment: http://www.xml-buddy.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm is looking good at $20 for the home eidtion

Comment: XMLMind (http://www.xmlmind.com/) has a personal edition (http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/download.shtml). I don't know if it has the required features (I never used it, just stumbled across it) and if you qualify for the personal edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XiMpLe (http://www.ximple.cz) is free for non-commercial use. And its grid view editor is good and comfortable. And there is no installation so you can try it quickly.

[image]

Comment: This looks even better than my own answer which I had accepted. Thanks. Free for non-commercial use and only Eur 30/user/year for commercial use; a  great price.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with [XML ValidatorBuddy](http://xml-buddy.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm) at $20 for the home edition .

It does just what I want

[image]

Comment: I still like this one. Also, its companion JSONbuddy. Greta features & great prices