# Recommendations For examining XML

Tags: windows, sql, data-analysis, data, xml

Are there any tools out there that are used to view and examine through large XML files?

I work for a small company as a Data Quality Analyst and a lot of my job is looking through large XML files that our clients send in.  Currently I just import the XML data into an Excel spreadsheet and work with it that way.  This brings about two problems though.  One, Excel really doesn't handle reading in large files really well.  It slows Excel down or completely crashes it.  Which slows down my process or makes it less accurate because I cannot view all the data at once.

Second being that it really doesn't flatten out the structure of the XML and results in an excel file that is bigger than it should be which is back to problem one.

My boss told me to research and see if there was something out there that can read in XML and allows me to do sorts and filters and can also handle decent size XML files.

The tool will run on Windows 10. We only need one license so if it comes to paying, hopefully no more than $100 (hard limit would be $200).

Comment: You may want to check out [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/884/xml-inspection-tool) and [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51396/gratis-xml-editor-with-grid-view), which are related to your question. Not exactly the same, but some of the same answers might serve your needs.

Comment: We currently have 730 [questions & answers that mention XML](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=xml). Maybe one of those might help? Welcome aboard, and good luck :-)

Comment: Take a look at [my similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51396/gratis-xml-editor-with-grid-view). It might help

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions, looking through them!